# How to access local data in new apps from previously deleted app

Tags: ios

User's profile in application include some data (like history in browser or tweets in twitter).

I want to use it in new application, **but user can delete old application**.

**What can help me to save this data without losing it when old application will be deleted and get this data when new application will be installed?**

Maybe there is some ways to save data in IPhone files, but I don't want user to see it.

Thanks

Comment: It's good idea to use ICloud, but I think about device memory or something this way, because I don't prefer to use Internet resources.

Comment: hence use the keychain. That is not reset / changed in any way by the deletion of an app.

Comment: Oh, it's interesting, thanks)

Answer (score 2):

You can save data in iCloud. Your applications can share iCloud data as long as they have the same bundle identifier prefix.

Alternatively, you can sync this data with your own (web) server.

It's up to you to write this functionality in your apps.

There is currently no shared document space on iOS. Each application is contained within a sandbox and cannot access documents stored in another application. Documents can be shared through [URL schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html), but this has to be launched from the originating app to the destination app (both apps must be installed at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

You can use iCloud data saving . [iCloud uses](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/after-deleting-an-app-can-you-much-later-reinstall-it-and-restore-its-data-fr)

What happens quite easily after a restore (for example after an update) is that iTunes restores the save data for all applications, but not the applications themselves. Therefore as soon as you install them , the old save data will be available (this applies to all apps, not just games). Just by itself nothing will be saved without backup.